# Remove only my root home page URL from Google search while allowing blog subdirectory to be indexed

Tags: google-search-console, url-removal

I have a website `example.com`, just a landing page with a `<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>` and linked to Google Search Console. It's appearing in searches.

I have another website called `example.com/blog`, installed with Wordpress, that wasn't linked to Google Search Console and is also appearing in searches.

For some reason I would like `example.com` to be gone from searches temporarily, but not `example.com/blog` with all its content. How should I do that?

I have Google Search Console attached but if I remove `example.com` URL from the [URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal), all the data from `example.com/blog` will also disappear from searches?

Comment: why not change the landing page meta to "noindex, follow" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL removal tool cannot be used to remove the home page and spare subpages at the same time.

On **subfolders**, the URL removal tool provides a choice to remove only the given URL or all URLs that begin with the given string:

[image: URL removal tool choices for a subfolder]

For the **home page**, there is no choice given but to remove the whole domain.

The safe solution would be a "noindex" on the home page, since it would permit further crawling and indexing on all other pages on the domain, with little side effects. If the search performance of you blog is a concern, I would not recommend it as a permanent setup though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Haven't done your recommendation because of the search performance that this may cause to my website.