# Does noindex for subpages affect the whole domain?

Tags: domains, url, noindex

I want to share the unreviewed version of my future website with a few people on an URL like this:
`example.com/hidden-unreviewed-version`

I would apply *noindex* on it and all its subpages to hide them from search engines. Later, the final version would be moved to the root of the same domain without *noindex*. Until then, the hidden subpages would be the only worthwhile content on the domain.

Will the *noindex* contaminate the whole domain for a long time, or do search engines consider the whole url of the page to be ignored?
The former hardly seems logical, but I want to be sure to avoid the risk.

(P.S. I found a [related answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120477/remove-only-my-root-home-page-url-from-google-search-while-allowing-blog-subdire/120497#120497), but that is about Google's URL removal tool, and not explicitly *noindex*, so my doubts were not dissipated.)

Comment: When you say "subpage" are you referring to a deeper URL that starts with that URL, or are you referring to pages that included into that page (say with iframes)?

Comment: The former. A deeper URL that starts with that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... **to answer your first question**, will "NOINDEX contaminate the whole domain"?
**Ans**: NO. It is just temporary as long as you have that NOINDEX tag on. So don't worry too much about your approach. Go for it.
More explanation, NOINDEX is a normal practice for any website to have some pages with a NOINDEX tag, just to tell search engines to NOT INDEX the site to the search result.

**Additionally:**
I would suggest you use ROBOTS.TXT files to disallow search engine bots to crawl these "unreviewed versions of your future website" in addition, as I sometimes see that the NOINDEXED page was acknowledged and shown on Google for some reason.